# On the universal and preconception in stoic logic: the word "natural" (naturale) from Diog. L., VII, 54

Tags: concept, stoicism, universals, nominalism

*Foreword: as an Italian student, I hope that I will not make many mistakes in translating the lexicon from my native language to English; sometimes this will happen, and so putting the Italian word in curved braces seems to me the best thing to do to avoid confusion or misinterpretation.*

Trying to understand stoic thought (especially stoic logic), I came across the doctrine of anticipation, which is the foundation for discussing stoic nominalism.

I understood that all the representations (rappresentazioni, from the greek *phantasia kataleptiké*) given by things from the real world leave a sign into the soul; after the representations disappear, what remains is a set of remembrances which, if the representations was of the same kind, is called "experience" (esperienza). The concepts arise from experience by a natural process called anticipation or common concept (nozione comune, form the latin *communes notitiae*, or from the greek *prólepsis*).

At this point, my textbook (1) says that

> "anticipation is the **natural** concept/notion of the universal" (or "l'anticipazione è la nozione **naturale** dell'universale"), from Diog. L, VII, 54.

From there the author starts talking about individual reality, and says that the universal exists only in anticipations, making stoic thought a form of nominalism.

The thing that I don't get is what does it mean for the *prólepsis* to be the *natural* notion/concept (nozione naturale) of the universal.

(1) Storia della filosofia, Volume 1; N. Abbagnano; UTET.

Comment: The English translation has "preconception" for "anticipazione".

Answer (score 1):

See English transl of [Lives, Book VII (Stoics), 54](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Lives_of_the_Eminent_Philosophers/Book_VII) :

> "The standard of truth they declare to be the apprehending presentation, i.e. that which comes from a real object – according to Chrysippus in the twelfth book of his *Physics* [...] while Chrysippus in the first book of his *Exposition of Doctrine* contradicts himself and declares that sensation and preconception are the only standards, preconception being a general notion which comes by the gift of nature (an innate conception of universals or general concepts)."

Thus, it seems that Diogenes Laertius attrbutes to [Chrysippus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysippus#Epistemology) a docrtine about the innate origin ( "gift of nature") of universals ("general concepts").

See also [Philosophy of Mind and Stoic Logic](https://www.iep.utm.edu/stoicmind/#H3) and [Chrysippus : Epistemology](https://www.iep.utm.edu/chrysipp/#H3).

For “implanted preconceptions” [*prolepseis*] see :Matt Jackson-McCabe, [The Stoic Theory of Implanted Preconceptions (2004)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4182760?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: First of all, thank you! If I understood well, the sentence "preconception is the natural notion of the universal" actually means that **a** preconception **is** a universal: preconceptions are notions (concepts, in the common meaning of the term - something like the Aristotelian concept of form, which is intelligible) obtained *from a natural process* (this is the meaning of "natural") form real things.

Comment: In fact seems to me that the problem with the interpretation of such sentence was only "linguistic": to say that "la prolessi è un concetto generale degli universali" (Diog. L. "Vite e dottrine dei più celebri filosofi", Bompiani) o "l'anticipazione è la nozione naturale dell'universale" is nothing more than a repetition of what I have reported one line above: from real things preconceptions ("le anticipazioni") are (the only) general concepts, obtained by a natural process (gift of nature), from Chrysippus.